# CSS: margin-left scale as function of image max-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2x Divs and 1x Img with the following CSS

```
#StageDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

#LogoDiv {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 135px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
}

#logoimg {
    /* max-width: 75%; /* */
    width: 1000px; /* */  
}
```

inside of #logoimg, I would like to use `max-width: 75%;` and then have `margin-left:` of both #LogoDiv and #StageDiv be a function of #logoimg as it changes

[image: current static layout]
http://jsfiddle.net/3KLUW/1/

Is this possible in pure CSS or will I have to do this in javascript in a `on resize` event? *(not sure what the actual function call is currently but im sure my buddy google will know)*  I think in the long run, I will most likely have to use a javascript event to scale my kineticjs stage anyway but I am curious to know if there is some CSS wizardry to do the first part.

Thoughts?

Edit:

```
window.onresize=function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('logoimg');
    var width = img.offsetWidth;
    var div = document.getElementById('LogoDiv');
    div.style.marginLeft= "-" + width/2 + "px";
};
```

still would be interested in a CSS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get away with a wrapper div for the whole logo:

```
<div id="logo">
  <div id="StageDiv">...</div>
  <div id="LogoDiv">
    <img id="logoimg" src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can set the `width` and `max-width` on it, and use `margin: auto` to center it on the page:

```
#logo {
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

And positioning the other elements become much easier:

```
#LogoDiv {
    top: 135px;
    position: absolute;
}

#StageDiv {
    text-align: center;
}

#logoimg {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `margin: auto` and `text-align: center` together give us the automatic margin you wanted.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KLUW/2/

The canvas will need to be scaled though, as you said on the question.

Comment: `margin: auto;` very nice, completely forgot about that